# Replace (A) column's value based on another (B) column's value in Microsoft PowerBI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I was wanting to check column (A) for a specific number then if/when found replace another columns (B) value with a text string in the same record.  Is there a simple way of doing this? I assumed it would be using the 'Replace Value'. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Before and after, what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "Replace Value" option in PowerBI is usually known as "search and replace" which works with static values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Query Editor, select **Add Column** > **Conditional Column**

This gives you a window by which you can specify the logic you wish to use. [image: Conditional Column]

I can't give you the logic to use, as your question does not include any example columns or data. But certainly, you can say "If column A equals 123, then output string xyz, otherwise output column B"

In the next step, you can delete column B, and rename this new conditional column as column B. While not technically the same as replacing the value directly in column B, the end result is the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is exactly what I needed to do. Was hoping to not have to use a Conditional Column, but this works.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm glad it was what you needed. Please do accept the answer, thank you!